# Add button linked to single product page on order detail page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, pages, order, review

I have write a code on functions.php so when customers click a button on order detail page, redirected to product page and review tab of the product they bought. But as a novice coder, I can't get the full link to the product page and the review tab. The code below if clicked is only going to http://mywebsite.com/shop/

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'tl_review_for_order');
function tl_review_for_order() { ?>
<a class="button-3" href="<?php echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ; ?>"><?php _e( 'REVIEW', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
<?php
}
```

So what I need is when the button clicked should go to the full link of the product page + review like http://mywebsite.com/shop/product-name/#tab-reviews

any one could solve this? Thanks

Comment: What if the user ordered more than one product?

Comment: the website is only allow one product pruchased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table` hook receives the `WC_Order` object as the `$order` argument. This means you can get the items from the order with `$order->get_items()`.

That will return an Array of `WC_Order_Item`s. From this you can get the associated product of the first item, which you can use to get its permalink, to which you can append `#tab-reviews`:

```
function tl_review_for_order( $order ) {
    // Get the order items.
    $order_items = $order->get_items();

    // Get the first or only order item.
    $order_item = reset( $order_items );

    // Get the product object from the order item.
    $product = $order_item->get_product();

    // Make sure the product still exists.
    if ( $product ) {
        // Output link using WooCommerce function for getting a product's link.
        printf(
            '<a class="button-3" href="%1$s#tab-reviews">%2$s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ),
            __( 'Review', 'woocommerce' )
        ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'tl_review_for_order' );
```

Note that I used `$product->get_permalink()` to get the URL, and not just `get_permalink()`. This is to maintain forwards compatibility for when WooCommerce products are no longer stored as posts. Something that is [not far off](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2018/07/17/woocommerce-custom-product-tables-beta/).

Comment: thanks for your help, but it ruins the (my-account/view-order/orderid) page, when the code is applied, the page only show the detail order data only and the customer billing address and other stuff are gone.

Comment: Sorry, I'd added `$order` to the `add_action()` by accident. Remove that.

Comment: still got the same behavior as before, no luck

Comment: Check your error log. I coded it blind so there's probably a typo in there somewhere.

Comment: its ok for the typho :D and the error Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500

Comment: Ok it turns out that the first array item from `get_items()` has an index of  `1`, for who knows what reason. Using `reset()` instead of `[0]` will work. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Syntax error unexpected T_variable on this line: $product = $order_item->get_product();

Comment: I left out a semi-colon. Check the answer again. Also, if you're going to copy untested code from strangers on the internet you should make sure to learn how to correct basic syntax issues yourself. :)

Comment: yes I do, I always read the code before applied it :)

Comment: Any way your code works great now. Thank you. I try to put this code on order-again.php so it will appear only when the order status is complete.